# Modify lines in a file between two matching strings using sed or awk in bash

Tags: regex, awk, sed

In bash how do I modify lines in yaml between two matching strings using awk or sed?

Like say I want lines between bbb and ddd modified,

```
aaa:
  bbb:
  - c1
  - c2
  - c3
  ddd: 111
```

should become,

```
aaa:
  bbb: ["c1","c2","c3"]
  ddd: 111
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
sed -e '/bbb:/,/ddd:/c\  bbb: ["c1","c2","c3"]\n  ddd: 111' myfile
```

Comment: But the problem  here is I dont know the yaml list elements. The c1, c2, c3 are just examples I have provided here. There could be any number of elements in there.

Comment: Oh... You're in case to deal with `awk` or a higher scripting langugage like PERL or Python (to name two that should be available on most systems)

Answer (score 0):

#### Disclaimer: Regex is not suitable for scalable structured data solutions. Please use a [dedicated YAML parser](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/) if at all possible.

```
awk -v key=bbb '
    NF == 1 && $1 == key ":" {flag=$0; next}
    flag != "" {
        if(sub(/^[\t ]*- /, "")) {
            array[NR] = $0; next
        } else {
            for(i in array) out = out "," "\"" array[i] "\""
            print flag, "[" substr(out,2) "]"
            split("", array) # POSIX delete array
            flag=out="" # POSIX delete variables
        }
    } {print}
'
```

*this is an extremely specific, brittle solution and should by no means ever be applied to general YAML parsing*

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/^\s*bbb:/{:a;N;/^\s*ddd:/M!ba;s/^\s*-\s*//mg;s/\n/","/g;s/",(.*),"/ [\1]\n/}' file
```

Gather up lines between `bbb:` and `ddd:`.

Remove extra spaces and `-` characters at the beginnings or lines.

Replace newlines by `","`.

Replace first `",` by `[` and last `,"` by `]\n`.